# When to use one to many or many to one in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Lets say I'm developing a polling app like [strawpoll.me](http://strawpoll.me). Would it be best to create my poll bean to contain a list of options or options to have a many to one relationship with a single poll? Also, when submitting the form to create a poll, does the database know to assign the foreign key in the OPTION table to the POLL_ID of the poll they belong to automatically? I know JPA makes database interactions simple but I cant find any examples that add objects with a one to many/many to one relationship at the same time.:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="POLL")
public class Poll implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @Column(name="POLL_ID")
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @Column(name="QUESTION_TEXT")
  private String question;

  @Column(name="CREATED_ON")
  private Timestamp dateCreated;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name="OPTION_ID")
  private List<Option> options = new ArrayList<Option>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="OPTION")
public class Option implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @Column(name="OPTION_ID")
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @Column(name="OPTION_TEXT")
  private String optionText;

  @Column(name="NUM_OF_VOTES")
  private int numOfVotes;
}
```

Or set up like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="POLL")
public class Poll implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @Column(name="POLL_ID")
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @Column(name="QUESTION_TEXT")
  private String question;

  @Column(name="CREATED_ON")
  private Timestamp dateCreated;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="OPTION")
public class Option implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @Column(name="OPTION_ID")
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne
  @Column(name="POLL_ID")
  private Poll poll;

  @Column(name="OPTION_TEXT")
  private String optionText;

  @Column(name="NUM_OF_VOTES")
  private int numOfVotes;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As I think there are room for improvement for the other 2 answers, I am giving mine)

What you are trying to do is actually quite common.  It is normally referred as Bi-directional one-to-many relationship. In your case it should look like:

```
class Poll {
    //....
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="poll")
    private Set<Option> options;
}

class Option {
    //...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("poll_id")  // I always like to be explicit on naming :P
    private Poll poll;
}
```

This gives you a more intuitive model.  It allow you to navigate from both sides (e.g. in HQL).

One confusion is usually: which side Hibernate is going to use to maintain the relationship in DB?  In Hibernate, there should be one side "owning" a relationship (what we shown above is one relationship, though bi-directional).  If you have `@JoinColumn` in both side, Hibernate will complain.  In our above example, by using `mappedBy`, Hibernate knows that it is the `Option` side owning the relationship.  You can see the difference if the `Poll` side and `Option` side is inconsistent (e.g. You have Poll-1 containing Option-1, but Option-1 pointing to Poll-2, and Poll-2 is not containing Option-1.  The result is, the `Option` table will be referring `Poll-2`)

Some pitfalls you should be aware.  What is described above about "owning relationship" is simply on the ORM aspect.  If you do not properly maintain your relationships in your model, your models may become inconsistent and will have problem if you are changing them in same session.  It is your obligation to make sure the relationship is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

It must be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="POLL")
public class Poll implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @Column(name="POLL_ID")
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @Column(name="QUESTION_TEXT")
  private String question;

  @Column(name="CREATED_ON")
  private Timestamp dateCreated;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="poll")
  private List<Option> options;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="OPTION")
public class Option implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @Column(name="OPTION_ID")
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="POLL_ID")
  private Poll poll;

  @Column(name="OPTION_TEXT")
  private String optionText;

  @Column(name="NUM_OF_VOTES")
  private int numOfVotes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA knows what table hooks up to it by entity name. If you have an `Option` entity, and your `Poll` entity contains a `List<Option>`, then JPA knows how to map one to another.

You DO NOT have to manage both sides of the relationship; if you add an `Option` to your `Poll` and persist the `Poll`, the `Option` will be updated as well. You don't have to go into the `Option` to set its `Poll`, so long as you're refreshing the `Option` from your data source before you use it again.

I prefer to manage the Many-to-One side, as it is less complicated on a case-by-case basis to tell a child entity which parent it belongs to. Otherwise, for example, adding a new entry to a `Set<Option>` would require the whole `Set` to be retrieved from the data source (for the purposes of comparing whether the set already contains it), while telling the `Option` which `Poll` it belongs to only needs to update one object.

Comment: One comment for `You DO NOT have to manage both sides of the relationship`.  For sake of persistence, you are right.  However, under same session, due to first level cache, if you have only applied the relationship on one side, it will NOT magically setup the other side for you.  It is always a good idea that, in your model's logic, keep both side of relationship consistent

Comment: True. Mapping both is best, though for the sake of consistency it's best to pick one side of the relationship to manage in your persistence code.

Comment: Thanks, you're answer was very helpful. I like the idea of telling the child class which parent it belongs to. But in the case of creating a poll, the poll itself is created at the same time as the options. So does JPA just know to assign the options with a foreign key to the POLL_ID? This is what confuses me the most.

Comment: Because you've defined an entity called `Option`, and an entity called `Poll` containing a One-to-Many List of `Option` items (and mapped it the other direction as well), JPA knows how to map them, based on the foreign-key columns you've defined in the `Poll` table and the `Option` table.

Comment: Okay got it. JPA just takes care of it. You mentioned its best to map in both beans in your previous comment. Would it look similar to the second answer below provided by @codeaholicguy

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Just the way you did it in the original post, just the version of each entity WITH the relationship mapped... `Poll` from the top part and `Option` from the bottom.

Comment: @SteveK I think you do not understand what I mean (or you misunderstood how it works in Hibernate).  You always need to map both side.  Hibernate won't allow  you to have both sides owning the relationship (try add `@JoinColumn` in both side).  It is not "best", you are "forced" to do so.  And the problem I am talking is not about ORM: if you do not maintain proper data consistency in model (even there is no ORM), your logic is going to be error-prone.  It is even worse with first level cache that, you are going to get the "inconsistent" obj even you thought you "re-enquired" it from DB

Comment: @AdrianShum you're absolutely correct. I should have put the example code in my answer, and it'd look pretty much like yours. Keeping the `@JoinColumn` annotation on the `List<Option>` in the `Poll` will break it, but the mapping annotation needs to exist in both entities. +1 for your answer.

Comment: @SteveK To be clear, keeping `@JoinColumn` on the `@OneToMany` side (with `mappedBy` in `@ManyToOne`) will still work, though there are some other implications.  The things does not work is having `@JoinColumn` in both side (even more precise, `@JoinColumn` with `updatable/insertable` etc `= true`)